# How to setup route for websocket server in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I have a setup similar to this one:

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server,
    express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app);

app.post("/login", login);
app.get("/...", callSomething);
// ...

server.listen(8000);


var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});

wss.on("connection", function(ws){
   // ...
});
```

I would like to put the WebSocketServer under a specific path which may for instance be `"...com/whatever"`. The question is how can I set the path? Is it possible?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You'll want to use the `path` option:

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server, path: "/hereIsWS"});
```

See full documentation [here](https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md)

Comment: Thanks ,but is it possible to move it completely away from app.js and put it to app.get("/hereIsWS", runServer) or I basically have to require file with the server?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You're trying to split your program into multiple files?  That should be fine - but you'll have to have access to the `server` object, not the `app` object.  `express` only handles normal http requests.

Comment: This answer is no longer current.

Comment: Awesome... Works for me with `new WebSocketServer({ port: x, path: y })`. How you found that from the README docs is a mystery to me 8-[

Comment: how to get client id when client connected?

Comment: It's in the typescript source code with has the interfaces and class of what you need. Yea annoying a little to find

Comment: This is a good method to specify ws path when http server has only one WebSocketServer. For multiple ws services, a more complicated solution is required: https://github.com/websockets/ws/pull/885

Answer (score 63):

Use express-ws:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws

**Installation:**

```
npm i express-ws -S
```

**HTTP server example:**

```
const express = require('express')
const enableWs = require('express-ws')

const app = express()
enableWs(app)

app.ws('/echo', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', msg => {
        ws.send(msg)
    })

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('WebSocket was closed')
    })
})

app.listen(80)
```

**HTTPS server example:**

**NOTICE** I strongly recommend making such features as HTTPS, compression and caching using an intermediate server between NodeJS and Internet, for example Nginx, it works much more efficiently and its configuration will be easier to change in the future

```
const https     = require('https')
const fs        = require('fs')
const express   = require('express')
const expressWs = require('express-ws')

const serverOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
}

const app       = express()
const server    = https.createServer(serverOptions, app)

expressWs(app, server)

app.ws('/echo', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', msg => {
        ws.send(msg)
    })

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('WebSocket was closed')
    })
})

server.listen(443)
```

**Browser client example:**

```
// wss: protocol is equivalent of https: 
// ws:  protocol is equivalent of http:
// You ALWAYS need to provide absolute address
// I mean, you can't just use relative path like /echo
const socketProtocol = (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss:' : 'ws:')
const echoSocketUrl = socketProtocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/echo/'
const socket = new WebSocket(echoSocketUrl);

socket.onopen = () => {
  socket.send('Here\'s some text that the server is urgently awaiting!'); 
}

socket.onmessage = e => {
  console.log('Message from server:', event.data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I started using this everywhere. `const enableWs = require('express-ws'); enableWs(app);` is **a lot** more readable than doing it the "normal" way.

Comment: I get this error when I try to connect from the web browser: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/echo' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`.

Comment: @Michael, I see you use wss protocol, which mean you use SSL. Does your server have valid certificate for this address and port? Maybe you just want to use ws:// protocol without SSL?

Comment: @Ujeenator Yes, it is a valid certificate with a CA recognized by the browser, and in fact the same server is already serving up the client page to the browser which is running the code that fails.

Comment: @Ujeenator It appears to be a problem with *express-ws*, not *ws* because if I try the "ExpressJS example" from the [ws page](https://github.com/websockets/ws) it works fine.

Comment: @Michael, I can't help until you share code to reproduce problem :)

Comment: @Ujeenator I found [this page](https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws/blob/master/examples/https.js) and from the deduced that I have to construct expressWs a bit differently when using https, namely along the lines of `var server = https.createServer(credentials, app); var expressWs = require("express-ws")(app,server)`.

Comment: I've seen the example many times BUT how do you send the CLIENT echo message up to the server?

Comment: @PeteAlvin I have added client example

Comment: A tip for the in-browser client. Might be useful to make the path to the server as follows: `'wss://' + window.location.hostname + '/your-path/'`

Comment: @Dmitry 

`(window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss:' : 'ws:') + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/your-path/'`

Comment: Avoid using express-ws as of 2020 - the package hasn't been updated in 2 years

Comment: This package is dead

Comment: express-ws seems to have no way of setting it up so that it selectively handles only certain routes.  For example, I am using http-proxy and I want to proxy some websockets to different servers, and handle some locally, but express-ws completely stomps all over the server upgrade handler and interferes with the proxy preventing correct WebSocket upgrades, yielding such mysterious errors as `Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code`

Comment: express-ws has a critical security issue: https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws/issues/120. Please avoid using it.

Comment: Well I picked up my project after 5 years and suddenly I find that something isn't working. Shouldn't I be able to mix ws and get requests on the same server?  But on the client, when I send a request to ws:// I get a "Unexpected server response: 404" (or 200 if I also define the same path as a get) because it's apparently not handling the request as ws:// at all!

Answer (score 23):

**UPDATE** Paths are valid in the ws server options.

```js
interface ServerOptions {
        host?: string;
        port?: number;
        backlog?: number;
        server?: http.Server | https.Server;
        verifyClient?: VerifyClientCallbackAsync | VerifyClientCallbackSync;
        handleProtocols?: any;
        path?: string;
        noServer?: boolean;
        clientTracking?: boolean;
        perMessageDeflate?: boolean | PerMessageDeflateOptions;
        maxPayload?: number;
    }
```

The accepted answer is no longer valid and will throw `Frame Header Invalid` errors. [Pull Request #885](https://github.com/websockets/ws/pull/885).

WS Paths were removed as [Lpinca](https://github.com/lpinca) puts it:

> The problem here is that each WebSocketServer adds a new listener for
>   the upgrade event on the HTTP server and when that event is emitted,
>   handleUpgrade is called on all servers.

Here is the work around:

```
const wss1 = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });
const wss2 = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });
const server = http.createServer();

server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  const pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

  if (pathname === '/foo') {
    wss1.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
      wss1.emit('connection', ws);
    });
  } else if (pathname === '/bar') {
    wss2.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
      wss2.emit('connection', ws);
    });
  } else {
    socket.destroy();
  }
});
```

Comment: Your linked issue is about mounting multiple socket paths with multiple socket servers. Not relevant to the question at all.

Comment: paths are not removed and still viable

Answer (score 19):

you could use this simple idea by putting incoming socket requests as a middleware, which I found to be pretty useful

in your app.js

```
const server = http.createServer(app)
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket.Server({server});
```

now put middleware there

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.ws = ws;
    return next();
});
```

or, which obviously is a bit simpler, this instead:

```
app.ws=ws;
```

now your ws construct is available in your routers, for example:

```
// main user dashboard GET
router.get('/', async function(req, res) {

        let ws = req.ws

        ws.once('connection', function connection(wss) {
            wss.on('message', function incoming(message) {
                console.log('received: %s', message);
            });

            wss.send(JSON.stringify('it works! Yeeee! :))' ));
        });
});
```

or if you attached it to your app by app.ws:

```
// main user dashboard GET
router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    req.app.ws.once('connection', (wss) => {
            console.log('connected:', req.app.ws.clients.size)
        });
});
```

pay very close attention to usage of "ws.once", not "ws.on", or you'll get multiple connections at new instances of websocket.server on each request.

Cheers! :)

Comment: I declared those variables in /bin/www and pasted middleware content in app.js and remaining in index.js. cannot pass the value ws through middleware

Comment: Have no idea what and how you did. Just follow the guideline I provided.

Comment: In this client side need to reload to get the new message. Is it so?

Comment: but why would you do this? I can see the advantage because routes. but do it still work the same?

Answer (score 14):

To build upon Ivan Kolyhalov's approach, it's possible to access the WebSocketServer from any endpoint by assigning it (or any of its properties) to `app.locals`.  Therefore, you only have to manage handling connections to the WebSocketServer in `server.js`.

In the code below we assign the `clients` property of the WebSocketServer to `app.locals`, which allows us to broadcast/push a custom message to all connected clients simply by making an HTTP request to the routed endpoints.

**server.js**

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
app.use("/api/pets", require("./routes/api/pets"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.info(`Server running on port: ${port}`));

const webSocketServer = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
webSocketServer.on("connection", (webSocket) => {

    console.info("Total connected clients:", webSocketServer.clients.size);

    app.locals.clients = webSocketServer.clients;
});
```

**./routes/api/pets.js**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const broadcast = (clients, message) => {

    clients.forEach((client) => {

        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {

            client.send(message);
        }
    });
};

router.get("/dog", (req, res) => {

    broadcast(req.app.locals.clients, "Bark!");

    return res.sendStatus(200);
});

router.get("/cat", (req, res) => {

    broadcast(req.app.locals.clients, "Meow!");

    return res.sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, all comments on this topic was very helpful for me to understand routing and ws, I'm kind off newbie there. I tried all, none of them was working for me.
My objectives was simply to add web socket to server.js which already have routes there.
And when I see solution by Ivan Kolyhalov, he was using req.ws for assigning web sockets in routers, so why not to use req.socket.server to get server obj there in router file. So, this is what I did, but it take sometime to figure it out. Please, let me know, if you think I did it wrong. PS. I handle disconnect on the client side and request upgrade via nginx proxy.

server.js

```
    express = require('express'),
    route1  = require('./routers/v1'),
    route2  = require('./routers/v2'),
    ws_route = require('./routers/api');
    http = require('http');
    app = express();

    const port = 3001;
    const server = http.createServer(app);

    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
    });

   app.use('/api', wsroute);
   app.use('/v1',  route1);
   app.use('/v2',  route2);
```

api.js

```
   const express = require("express");
   const router = express.Router();
   var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
   const wslib =  require('../server/ws_lib');

   router.get('/stats', async function (req, res) {
        wsserver = req.socket.server;
        var wss = new WebSocketServer({server:wsserver});
        wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, request) {
             console.log(new Date() + ' | A new client is connected.');
             console.log("Total Number of clients",wss.clients.size);
             var  connectionParams;
             var [_path, params] = request.url.split("?");
             connectionParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
             console.log('Using path', _path);
             var refresh_rate = 1000;
             if ( ! connectionParams.has("app")){
                 intid = wslib.send_messages_with_interval(wss, refresh_rate, "all", wslib.build_message);
             }
             else{
                 var app=connectionParams.get("app");
                 intid= wslib.send_messages_with_interval(wss, refresh_rate, app, wslib.build_message);
             }
             ws.on('close', () => {
                 console.log('Client has disconnected!');
                 clearInterval(intid);
             });
        });
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This will create a new web socket server on each /stats request. You probably don't want this. You probably want a new instance of a socket connection created when your app boots up, like the other posts. Then when a request comes in it will 'subscribe' the requestor to the (single) already running web socket server. If a new update happens, your code can then loop through the clients connected and broadcast to each requestor 'subscribed' to the web socket server.