# Websocket server not starting concurrently with node server

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm trying to write a simple WebSocket server app based in Nodejs, but I am unable to get it started when I run `npm run dev`.

This is my `package.json` file:

```
"name": "lg-chain",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "dev-test": "nodemon dev-test",
    "start": "node ./app",
    "dev": "nodemon ./app"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "nodemon": "1.18.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "ws": "6.1.3"
  }
}
```

I developed both an http server and websocket server and my expectation is that they both will start when I run that command I mentioned above.

Below is my websocket server:

```
const Websocket = require('ws');


const P2P_PORT = process.env.P2P_PORT || 5001;
const peers = process.env.PEERS ? process.env.PEERS.split(',') : [];

class P2pServer {
    constructor(blockchain) {
        this.blockchain = blockchain;
        this.sockets = [];
    }

    listen() {
        const server = new Websocket.Server({ port: P2P_PORT });
        server.on('connection', socket => this.connectSocket(socket));

        this.connectToPeers();

        console.log(`Listening for peer-to-peer connections on: ${P2P_PORT}`);
    }

    connectToPeers() {
        peers.forEach((peer) => {
            const socket = new Websocket(peer);

            socket.on('open', () => this.connectSocket);
        });
    }

    connectSocket(socket) {
        this.sockets.push(socket);
        console.log('Socket connected');
    }
}

module.exports = P2pServer;
```

And this is my express server:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Blockchain = require('../blockchain');
const P2pServer = require('./p2p-server');

const HTTP_PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
const bc = new Blockchain();
const p2pServer = new P2pServer(bc);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/blocks', (req, res) => {
    res.json(bc.chain);
});

app.post('/mine', (req, res) => {
    const block = bc.addBlock(req.body.data);
    console.log(`New block added: ${block.toString()}`);

    res.redirect('/blocks');
});

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${HTTP_PORT}`));
p2pServer.listen();
```

My express server starts up, but absolutely nothing happens with my websocket server. I don't get any errors anywhere. How do I begin troubleshooting this with websockets?

Comment: Try my solution which is far simpler than yours. Maybe it will forward you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429744/how-to-setup-route-for-websocket-server-in-express/54268611#54268611

Comment: @IvanKolyhalov, thank you for your reply. But what I would like to know is why my solution is not working. It seems to me that `p2pServer.listen();` is doing nothing. And so I am wondering why is it not doing anything? And how can I read an error or a log somewhere of what is going on?

Comment: Apparently I had duplicate server files. Can someone guide me as to whether I should document that as an answer or simply remove the post?