# socket io Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to remove Listener to avoid this problem in socket io once the event is done.

I am getting this error

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 connection listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

I have tried using removeAllListeners / removeListener / off but none of them work.

```
const io = socket(httpServer); 

(async () => {
  await io.on('connection', async function (client) {

       // Some Code //

        await client.emit('message', "Done")
        io.removeAllListeners("connection")
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `await io.once` instead of `await io.on` if you want single socket connection with single client. Otherwise it generates multiple instances of server listeners with every request to server-side.

Comment: It didn't work since this async IIFE function is inside another function which gets fired every time something happens on client side.

Comment: Well then you have to restructure your code logic. You have to invoke io.once in app.js at startup and then listen to events via req.io. You have to attach socket to your app, but you invoke it at every request. Check this answer related to websockets. Generally it is the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429744/how-to-setup-route-for-websocket-server-in-express/54268611#54268611

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I am able to resolve the issue by using the below code,

```
mqttClient.off('message', mqttClient.listeners("message")[0])
```

- it will remove the required listener form the event.

`mqttClient.listeners("message")` : I will return the array of listner attached to the "message" event.

You can use `removeListner()` as well
Here I have used MQTT case. you can follow this process for `socket io` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace that warning using `--trace-warnings` (should work in `node` , `nodemon` and `babel-node`).

In my case, using MySQL in Node I had this error:

```
(node:44) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

at _addListener (events.js:247:17)

at PoolConnection.addListener (events.js:263:10)

at /app/server.js:100:1 // Redacted, but here's the specific line and column for the error 

at Ping.onOperationComplete (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:110:5)

at Ping.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)

at Ping._callback (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)

at Ping.Sequence.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)

at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:92:8)

at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)

at Parser._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
```

This was the issue:

```
const mysql_pool = mysql.createPool(mysql_pool_options);

// ...

io.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('foobar', function(foo) {
    // Stuff going on ...

    // Get connection and query the database 
    mysql_pool.getConnection(function(err, current_mysql_connection) {
       current_mysql_connection.query(my_great_query, function(query_error, results) {
           // Some other stuff I do ...
       });

       //   Here's the issue, I didn't need to do this here  
       current_mysql_connection.on('error', function(err) {
           // console.log(err);
       });
    });
  });
});
```