# Create routes in websockets and node/express

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, routes, ws

I am trying to somehow have some separation of my WS code in my node/express. I want to have some routes in my WS code, like the API routes that express has. I am using the [ws module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)

I guess I could use something out of the box like [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws), but is there a way to do this without using any extra npm module? I dont want to deploy another module because less modules means a more minimal and easy to maintain project. Also, if I do this without a module I will better understand how WS work.

I guess I could put some parts of the WS in a separate js file, export it and then include it in my `app.js`. But do I also need to import WS in that file, since I need the `.on('something'` events?

```
broadcast.js file
 //include 
const  broadcast = (wss) =>{
  var broadcast = function() { 
      var jsonmsg = JSON.stringify({
      message: 'hello'
  });

  // wss.clients is an array of all connected clients
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      client.send(jsonmsg);
      console.log('Sent: ' + jsonmsg);
    });
  }
} 

exports.broadcast = broadcast;


and then use it like
const bc = require('./broadcast.js');
bc.broadcast(wss);
```

By separating the WS layer, I could also use WS routes, to have different endpoints for different tasks. How can I create WS routes? I can maybe work with the `path` of the ws module ?

`var wss = new wsserver({ port: 5001 , path: "/flip"})`

and move the code for `flip` to another file? I am not sure how to do this and based on a little testing I did, the same WS port does not support multiple paths

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup route for websocket server in express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429744/how-to-setup-route-for-websocket-server-in-express)

Comment: @codebot, if you're still having this problem (2 years later), I've posted a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773285/defining-websocket-routes-for-express/69773286#69773286